# How to pass value from controller to model in ROR3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i m new to ROR3.0 
controller code

```
def create
   @data = Checking.check(arg1,arg2,arg3,agr4)
end
```

model code

```
def self.check
   @vl1=arg1
   @vl2=arg2
   @vl3=arg3
   @vl4=arg4
end
```

how to pass value from controller to model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the arguments list for the model class method.

```
def self.check(arg1,arg2,arg3,agr4)
   @vl1=arg1
   @vl2=arg2
   @vl3=arg3
   @vl4=arg4
end
```